# uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewSection view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003721110'

Tags: swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

The error occurs when I go into my settings view controller. Settings has a UISegmentedControl which is connected to theme.swift through SettingsViewcontroller.swift ViewDidLoad().

I've been following a tutorial, but got an error about the Theme enum which went away when I added the Int value type to the enum declaration. Theme is returned by the ThemeManager struct with a rawValue.

I'm pretty sure the error is being caused by settingsViewController.swift. Since the only code that is executed when the settingsViewController.swift is loaded is in the viewDidLoad() method, I'm thinking the problem lies there.

The reason for the uncaught exception is 'UITableViewSection view', which I'm guessing is the UISegmentControl, as the only other section is an apply button, whose code isn't run until it's pressed?!

I've been reading about similar errors, and have gathered that a method is being called on an object that doesn't contain said method. I don't see anything like that, but I'm not sure about line 30 in Theme.swift. I had to change the tutorial code because of multiple errors. Either that or the Theme enum shouldn't be an Int (line 13 Theme.swift).

```
Theme.swift

import UIKit

let SelectedThemeKey = "SelectedTheme"

enum Theme : Int {
    case Default, Dark, Graphical

    var mainColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .Default:
            return UIColor(red: 87.0/255.0, green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case .Dark:
            return UIColor(red: 242.0/255.0, green: 101.0/255.0, blue: 34.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case .Graphical:
            return UIColor(red: 10.0/255.0, green: 10.0/255.0, blue: 10.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ThemeManager {
    static func currentTheme() -> Theme {
        if let storedTheme = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: SelectedThemeKey) as AnyObject).integerValue {
            return Theme(rawValue: storedTheme)!
        } else {
            return .Default
        }
    }

    static func applyTheme(theme: Theme) {
        // 1
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(theme.rawValue, forKey: SelectedThemeKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        // 2
        let sharedApplication = UIApplication.shared
        sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = theme.mainColor
    }
}

SettingsViewcontroller.swift

import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var themeSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var applyButton: UIButton!

    //@IBOutlet weak var settingsTableView: UITableView!

    //let settingsTableOptions = ["Turn On Dark Mode"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register custom cell
        //let nib = UINib(nibName: "settingsTableCell", bundle: nil)
        //settingsTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Settings")

        themeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = ThemeManager.currentTheme().rawValue
    }

    func dismiss() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func applyTheme(sender: UIButton) {
        if let selectedTheme = Theme(rawValue: themeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            ThemeManager.applyTheme(theme: selectedTheme)
        }
        dismiss()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    }
}



I've setup the story board for the settings view exactly as the tutorial, and don't recognise any options that could cause my problem.
```

Comment: The error mentions `UITableViewSection`. There must be a custom class `UITableViewSection` and this class causes the error. By the way, you can reduce `currentTheme()` to one line: `return Theme(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: SelectedThemeKey))!`. `integer(forKey` returns `0` by default if the key does not exist. And don't use `setValue(:forKey`, use `set(:forKey`. And don't use `synchronize()`

Comment: @vadian Clicking around UI elements in document outline view, I only see UITableView (not UITableViewSection) under custom classes in inspector window. I've got 2 sections in a UITableViewController for a segmented controller (theme selector) and an apply button. I assume this is the UITableViewSection mentioned in the debug window. Thanks for the extra tips, I've put them in!

Comment: Instead of *clicking around* press ⇧⌘F and type or paste `UITableViewSection`. Are there any search results?

Comment: @vadian No results in a whole of project search. In the mean time, I'm gonna read about setting debug breakpoints (as was mentioned in a similar post).